# Error changing language in the create view of a contact form using mail_form gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contact-form, mail-form

I have an error changing the language using I18n in my creates view for the contact form of my web page. This error is caused because creates uses the method Post and the link_to uses get. In order to solve this problem I used a link_to_unless arrange:

```
      <li><%= link_to_unless( current_page?(:controller => 'contacts', :action => 'create'),(t ('layouts.language1')) , change_locale_path(:es)) do
                                        link_to (t ('layouts.language1'), change_locale_path(:es), method: :post)
                            end%></li>
```

But it still not working. I want that the create view refreshes to the other language when I choose it in my Dropdown menu. Does anybody know how to deal with this issue? I really appreciate your answers. Thank you

Comment: Hi Raj as I said the error is a routing one: Routing error. No route matches [GET]/"Contacts". That is why I made that arrange with link_to_unless.

Comment: Are your app is Js enabled and have included all required js files? Also, I think you should use `button_to` instead of `link_to` for POSTing on server

Comment: yes all were included in the application.js and all the functionalities of my javascripts are working ecpting the link_to with :method =>"post". Apart from that, my routes file is:

Comment: resources :contacts, only: [:new,:create]

  get 'gmm/home' 

  get 'gmm/about'

  get 'gmm/services'

  get 'gmm/contact'

  get '/change_locale/:locale', to: 'settings#change_locale', as: :change_locale

Comment: Hi raj I am using link_to because I am using a dropdown menu. But I dont think that will affect a lot why method: :post is not working

Comment: I see. Thanks for posting the info. It would be great if you can post your raw error log too.

Comment: Hi Raj this is my error log. http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mfG1e5Xfj3Y/Vou0349EszI/AAAAAAAAAdU/rKP8N7tQSHE/s1600/problem2.jpg" imageanchor="1" ><img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-mfG1e5Xfj3Y/Vou0349EszI/AAAAAAAAAdU/rKP8N7tQSHE/s320/problem2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I am not sure why you are trying to add `link_to` within a `link_to_unless`, however, I think you should use following code to accomplish your need:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to_unless(current_page?(:controller => 'contacts', :action => 'create'),
                     t('layouts.language1'),
                     change_locale_path(:es)),
                     method: :post %>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Raj I tries you way there is an error with one of the brackets. It must be.

          <li>
  <%= link_to_unless(current_page?(:controller => 'contacts', :action => 'create'),
                     t('layouts.language1'),
                     change_locale_path(:es),
                     method: :post )%>
</li>. But then I get this error.  "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-lf1URK4Iw-c/Vou45A5VSaI/AAAAAAAAAdg/58W7QBZz5NM/s1600/problem3.jpg" imageanchor="1" ><img border="0" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-lf1URK4Iw-c/Vou45A5VSaI/AAAAAAAAAdg/58W7QBZz5NM/s320/problem3.jpg"

Comment: which makes sense because I am trying to use change_locale_path. Then, The problem is the same one, How to change the language of the create view while staying there because the url is called by the method post and not the get one.